# Is it possible to alter the source video a youtube ID refers to?

Tags: php, youtube-api

Using the Zend_Gdata php library, is it possible to edit an existing youtube video entry to have a new source video? The use-case is I'm ebedding a timelapse recording of construction work, and I'd like to update the video each evening without changing the embed link each time.

If this is not possible, is there another way I can achieve this without requiring the embed code to be changed each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a playlist, and update the playlist elements all days without changing the embed code. You can use the YouTube Data API to change the playlist elements:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems